# NUnit "could not load file or assemby 'MyTestProject'

Tags: .net, 64-bit, nunit, continuous-integration

I'm setting up a new 64 bit machine to run as a build server.  When I try to load my NUnit test assembly into NUnit GUI I get the following error.

There is nothing obvious missing, all the dependencies seem to be present. All the DLLs are compiled for the x86 platform.

Using NUnit 2.4.7.  I have tried upgrading to 2.4.8 but the same error occurs.

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could
>   not load file or assembly
>   'MyTestProject' or one of it's
>   dependencies. The system cannot find
>   the file specified.

System.IO.FileNotFoundException...

```
Server stack trace: 
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString)
   at NUnit.Core.Builders.TestAssemblyBuilder.Load(String path)
   at NUnit.Core.Builders.TestAssemblyBuilder.Build(String assemblyName, Boolean autoSuites)
   at NUnit.Core.Builders.TestAssemblyBuilder.Build(String assemblyName, String testName, Boolean autoSuites)
   at NUnit.Core.TestSuiteBuilder.BuildSingleAssembly(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Core.TestSuiteBuilder.Build(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Core.SimpleTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Core.ProxyTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Core.ProxyTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Core.RemoteTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at NUnit.Core.TestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Util.TestDomain.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Util.TestLoader.LoadTest(String testName)
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The solution was to build the test project for "AnyCPU" instead of 32-bit.  I can work around the restriction that made us use 32 bit.

Thank you David and Joe90 for the suggestions.  I've certainly learned a couple of new things. fuslogvw.exe is awesome, I didn't previously know it existed.

Comment: yes, but it's better to use nunit-x86 if you need your project to be compiled to x86.

Comment: Thanks NeedHack! Saved me from further headaches. Maybe the error messages should be a bit clearer.  tsk

Answer (score 11):

If you do need to build the test project for x86, you can use nunit-x86.

See "NUnit on 64-Bit Platforms" at http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=nunit-gui&r=2.4.2.

Answer (score 5):

Activate the Fusion log with [`fuslogvw.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx) (Run as Administrator from the Visual Studio Command Prompt) to see what the assembly loader tries to load and all occurring errors.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was found following this post: ["Could not load file or assembly 'X.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found." - on host server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7472421/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-x-dll-or-one-of-its-dependencies-the-specifi) and more specifically by using http://dependencywalker.com/