# "Could not load file or assembly 'X.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found." - on host server

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7

The X.dll is my C++/CLI dll, placed in the bin folder of the website. It works OK on local machine and initially it worked OK on the server. But I changed hosting accounts and suddenly I got this error. Should I somehow reference this assembly in the web.config? I've heard there are issues like this with unmanaged dlls, but the assembly in question is managed.
Full message:

> Could not load file or assembly 'X.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found. at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies() at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods() at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) Could not load file or assembly 'X.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found. at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective)
>   at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies() at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods() at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely there is an additional DLL the DLL in question is trying to find.

Dependency Walker may be able to help you.

http://dependencywalker.com/

Comment: I ruled out this possibility since he said that initially worked ok on the server.

Comment: I thought when he said he changed hosting accounts it meant he went to a new server.  If it is just running under a new account, the environment, in particular the PATH, may be different.

Comment: Can you clarify things for Steve and I? What does 'changed hosting accounts' mean? What was the actual change that was made, that effectively broke it?

Comment: I cancelled my shared hosting plan and then I bought it again in the same hosting company a few days later. So really I don't what changed in the server configuration (I don't even know it's the same machine).

Comment: Yep, it was MSVCR100.dll - I assumed it would be present on the server.

Comment: Probably some application was installed on the original server that installed MSVCR100.dll in a "public" place so your application had access to it.   Glad you are up and running!

Comment: it was msvcr110d.dll . I tried to run nunit tests on a PC having only the visual studio shell, while the test was compiled on a machine with full visual studio version.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a classic permssions issue. Try giving the web server permission on the file?

Comment: How can I do this? (I'm noob with server/system stuff)

Comment: Find the file - right click, properties - Security Tab -- Add read and execute permissions for the IIS User account. This will vary depending on OS. Could be ASPNET, IUSR_<machinename>, or IIS_IUSRS.

Comment: This is a shared hosting, I don't think I can do this (?).

Comment: You had enough rights on the box to put the web app into place, right? If so, you should have access to be able to modify the security permissions on the files that you placed on the server.

Comment: Through the web interface I can set read and write permissions only and I don't even know how these relate to IIS. Help!

Answer (score 0):

As already said before, it's related to a missing DLL.

I have always used the [Microsoft Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to track down the root cause of such issues.

Use it like this:

- Use the filter button to filter by Process Name `w3wp.exe`.
- Delete the existing lines using the corresponding button.
- Then start your app and perform the action.

The appearing list will hopefully show some lines with `file not found`.